# HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed Ошибка

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("people")
public class PeopleController{

private PersonDAO personDAO;

@Autowired
public PeopleController(PersonDAO personDAO) {
    this.personDAO = personDAO;
}

@GetMapping()
public String index(Model model) {
    System.out.println(personDAO.getPeople().size());
    model.addAttribute("people",personDAO.getPeople());
    return "people/people_show";
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String show(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("person",personDAO.getPerson(id));
    return "people/person_show";
}

@GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
    model.addAttribute("person",personDAO.getPerson(id));
    return "people/edit";
}

@PatchMapping("/{id}")
public String update(@PathVariable("id") int id,@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
    personDAO.update(id,person);
    return "redirect:/people";

}
```

}

в DispatcherServletInitializer

```
    public void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext context) {
    context.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
            new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,true,"/*");

}
```

страница:
https://pastebin.com/wk9aFEb5

Не могу понять, в чем проблема